Energy conservation in alpha particle induced nuclear reaction
Regarding the alpha particle induced nuclear reaction- $${}^{16}_7N+{}^{4}_2He--->{}^{1}_1H+ {}^{19}_8O $$ The alpha particle collides with stationary Nitrogen isotope to give the following reaction. I do not understand the mechanism of the reaction, i have studied that-
The alpha particle has some initial K.E with which it collides with N isotope, this collision is considered perfectly inelastic,whatever energy that the alpha particle loses, since it is a inelastic collision, is the energy that is used as ignition energy for the reaction or we can say that this energy accounts for the mass defect i.e extra mass in product.
Doubts-
1.Why the collision is considered inelastic and why not elastic?
2.If only the energy alpha particle losses is the energy that intiates the reaction(i hope this is what meant by ignition energy ) or is the energy that takes part in reaction,then what about the energy left with the alpha particle as its K.E, why its not in the product,how do we account for that energy?

At the level of subatomic collisions, all collisions must strictly conserve both energy and momentum. The definition of elastic v.s. inelastic in this context is that elastic collisions preserve the identity of the particles coming in and out, whereas inelastic collisions can change, say, at least the excitation state of the incoming particles. Here, the particle identity itself changed, so it must be inelastic. As for the energy of the alpha particle, it will be returned in the final product. It is just that this initial KE is too small compared to the liberated energy that it doesnt matter.

what is the 'liberated energy', there is no  +Energy term in the product,if it really is there is it coming from binding energy of N isotope ? I ask this because when i apply energy conservation to the equation i see mass potential energies and total k.e of alpha particle being redistributed as activation energy of reaction and k.E of product, only these two.

I have not stated any "liberated energy". But in this reaction the energies are redistributed. None of the rest mass energies of nitrogen, oxygen, helium nor hydrogen is the same, and thus there is no way for the collision's "initial relative KE" to be equal to the "final relative KE", whatever you might choose to define such a thing. This immediately leads to the collision to be inelastic rather than elastic.

The collision is considered inelastic because after the collision the two colliding particles combine together so the velocity of separation between the two particles is zero immediately after the collision which gives coefficient of restitution $e=0$ so collision is "inelastic". A part of "The Kinetic Energy of alpha particle" is then used to provide the activation energy for the nuclear reaction. The remaining energy is then converted back to kinetic energy providing the new entities formed some velocity in accordance to the conservation of momentum.
One may argue that if the products formed do have some velocity and thus velocity of separation then why is the coefficient of restitution "$0$".
It is because the original colliding entities had $0$ velocity of separation just after the collision and the products formed are different entities who are imparted the velocity so the 2 can not be co-related.

I understood few things but -["A part of "The lost Energy" is then used to provide the activation energy for the nuclear reaction. The remaining ... momentum."].  You said 'a part of lost energy' but i think its 'a part of total K.E of alpha particle is lost energy and this lost energy completely becomes activation energy while the remaining energy is left as K.E of the new mass formed by inelastic collision'. Am i still reading this wrong?

Yes that is what I meant there as the kinetic energy of the alpha particle is lost

So you just made a typo? If yes, could you please correct it in original answer

@SHINU_MADE Sure!

No, the question did not state that the products are stuck together. The coefficient of restitution is not zero.

@naturallyInconsistent i have stated the reason why coefficient of restitution is zero and and yes i have also considered the fact that the products do have some final kinetic energy and they are not stuck together you might want to read the answer again and thoroughly.

No, by your argument every repulsive potential direct collision would have a point at which the coefficient of restitution is zero. That is just nonsense and extremely sloppy argumentation.

@naturallyInconsistent i understand what you mean I am just unable to make you understand my point because I am not much good in English, what you have said in the comments above I tried to mention the same point but I think my word just don't matchup it will be helpful if you suggest edits in it

In terms of atomic masses, the particle which collide have a combined mass of $16.006101+4.002603= 20.0088704$ amu and the products have a combined mass of $1.007825+19.003578 = 20.011403$ amu.
Thus, mass after > mass before.
Thus this reaction occur without the addition of extra energy which comes from the kinetic energy of the alpha particle.
In chemical parlance it is an endothermic reaction and can only occur if there is an input of energy which you might call activation energy?
There is the additional constraint that momentum must be conserved thus the outgoing particles must have some kinetic energy which must be included when balancing energies.
Given that the total kinetic energy must be reduced you could call this an inelastic collision, less kinetic after the reaction than kinetic energy before the reaction.
A similar reaction was observed by Rutherford and further analysed by Blackett, link 1 and link 2.
